# Asking proper do loop fortran

Tags: loops, fortran, k-means

I write a code, for measuring distance k means.

So, r is array for my data points. I want to reduce every coordinate of data point with every centroid. So, flow are like, J only change if y=k . Meanwhile i should be keep on going (i number should keep updated +1). distance is 2d array, and Z is the column indeks. Distance is empty 2d array that the value will be filled by result of reduction, that is why the value of i should be updated for every calculation. N is number of data points, and k is number of cluster. z, k , and n is different value.

the problem my with my current code,

```
do i=1,z
   do j=1,n
      y=1
     do while 
        y<=k 
        distance(1,i)=abs( r(1,j) - centroid (1,y) )
        distance(2,i)=abs( r(2,j) - centroid (2,y) )
        y=y+1
     end do
   end do
end do
```

The problem with this is, the i value is not keep updated. I need i value keep increase, +1

Comment: Hi Dono Don, welcome to Stack Overflow :) I'm afraid your question is very confusing. What is `z` supposed to be? When is it supposed to be updated? If you haven't already looked at them, you might want to check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm still confused; if `z` is a column index, why is it also the upper limit on the outer loop? What is the outer loop supposed to be doing?

Comment: Also, what are `k` and `n`? Are they constants, or are they supposed to change through the loop?

Comment: Like @veryreverie I really can not follow what you are trying to say. Is it as simple as in `distance(1,z)` you should replace `z` with `i`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the attention and correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something of a guess, as I'm still confused by your question, but is this what you want?

```
i = 0
do j=1,n
  do y=1,k
    i = i+1
    distance(:,i) = abs(r(:,j)-centroid(:,y))
  enddo
enddo
```

So looping `j` over the `r` array, `y` over the `centroid` array (but only up to `k`), and incrementing `i` for each combination of the two?

This assumes that the `distance` array is large enough that `i` doesn't overrun it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the i value, (in my case z, shape for array should be predefined to allocate array fortran ). Apparently not

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't fully understand. Are you saying `i` or `z` should be predefined? You still have to allocate `distance` before you can add values to it.

Comment: Yes, but previously I thought z value should be fixed i.e 30. I dont know we can put zero first and dynamically changed. thats why i made do i=1,z . I assuumed so because I often get error 'array cannt have deferred shape' . I thought that means that we have to fixed the number.

Comment: The size of your array has to be fixed when you allocate it (although it can be changed later with a re-allocation). But `i` is a variable; you can change it however you like. All that matters is that you don't call `distance(foo,i)` with `i` greater than the second dimension of `distance`.